# In Django project Media folder is not getting created

Tags: django

There is no media folder in the project, and i can see the media in db, but it won't load on template. 
With this error:

> Not Found: /DSC_0008.JPG

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('UserProfile.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

index.html looks something like this:

```
<div class="profile-userpic">
                    <img src="{{ my_details.associate_image.url }}" width="150" height="150" class="img-responsive" alt="my pic">
                </div>
```

Comment: Are you using dev server in localhost?

Comment: That error is saying that you tried to load /DSC_0008.JPG, not /media/DSC_0008.JPG. How did you generate that link? Show the template.

Comment: `but it won't load on template`, show the html how you are loading it.

Comment: <div class="profile-userpic">
     <img src="{{ my_details.associate_image.url }}" width="150" height="150" class="img-responsive" alt="my pic">
    </div>

Comment: yes i am using dev server as localhost

Answer (score 0):

For development server,

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This will create your media folder when DEBUG = True in your settings.

Make sure your image path `{{ my_details.associate_image.url }}` is correct. The media url must be like `127.0.0.1:8000/media/..filename.ext..`

Comment: the problem is in my file structure i cannot see media folder